# random.random() generates different numbers on different machines

Tags: python, random, raspberry-pi

on a raspberry pi 3:

```py
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(0.9849899567458751)
>>> random.random()
0.47871160253065614
```

on my laptop (running Ubuntu):

```py
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(0.9849899567458751)
>>> random.random()
0.5059711320067936
```

I need those two numbers to be equal. My guess would be that this has something to do with floating point precision that might be different on the two machines but I don't know how to solve this.

How do I generate reproducable random numbers in python, regardless of the machine the code is running on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an integer for the `seed` instead of a floating-point number.

Python 3.5.3 on Raspberry Pi:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(9248459222926972)
>>> [random.randint(1, 1000) for x in range(5)]
[586, 818, 989, 122, 519]
```

Python 3.7.3 on Windows x64:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(9248459222926972)
>>> [random.randint(1, 1000) for x in range(5)]
[586, 818, 989, 122, 519]
```

In case you're working with library code that might be calling `random.*()` "in the background", you may also want to consider instantiating your own seeded RNG only your code uses:

```py
import random
rng = random.Random()
rng.seed(9248459222926972)
# ...
```

Comment: that's interesting. Do you know if seeding with floating-point numbers causes other problems as well?

Comment: Based on https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c879ff247ae1b67a790ff98d2d59145302cd4e4e/Modules/_randommodule.c#L271-L285 it looks like everything that's not an integer gets `hash()`ed, and hash values are randomized per interpreter start by default.